# AdMob, не загружается реклама

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

Добавил в приложение баннер AdMob и тестировал на тест-рекламе, все отлично, все показывает. Но только меняю на реальные данные - белый экран баннера, и в листенере идет запуск метода `onAdFailedToLoad`. На сайте AdMob нашел функцию, в которой сообщалось, что надо отправить заявку и получить одобрение на рекламу. Отправил - результат такой же. По сути, код должен быть без ошибок, т.к. тест-релкама работает, но реальная нет.

`<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-11111111~11111111111"/>`

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-111111111111~111111111111")

    val mAdView = findViewById<AdView>(R.id.adView)
    mAdView.loadAd(getAdRequest())

private fun getAdRequest(): AdRequest {
    return AdRequest.Builder().build()
}



<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2994842643091713/7618573718">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: попробуйте формат поменять на BANNER

Comment: До этого был BANNER, но сути это не меняет.)

Comment: а ошибка какая onAdFailedToLoad?

Comment: Да там вылетает 'toast', который я поставил

Comment: повторяю еще раз - нужен код ошибки

Comment: onAdFailedToLoad 3

Comment: ваш account AdMob был забанен когда-нибудь или данное приложение? в Фильтрах что-то меняли?

Comment: Нет. Я создал новый аккаунт, отправил заявку на рекламу - получил одобрение. Спустя 2 дня такая же ситуация, её нет. Делал релиз приложения - ситуация та же.

Comment: а сколько времени прошло? если меньше недели то ждите

Comment: 2 дня с момента регистрации. Окей, спасибо, и за подсказку посмотреть код ошибки тоже, что-то не подумал.

Comment: MobileAds.initialize один раз делаете?

Comment: Да, один. Я почему-то не думаю, что ошибка где-то в коде, т.к. тест-реклама работает на отлично.

Comment: Все, появилась реклама, спасибо за советы. :)

Answer (score 2):

Во первых лучше не тестируйте показ реальной рекламе на Вашем устройстве, могут забанить аккаунт за привлечение некачественного трафика. Во вторых- если показывается тестовый баннер, тогда поменяйте его на реальную рекламу, подписывайте приложений в студии и публикуйте в магазине. Через 1-3 дня будет показываться реальная реклама.

Comment: Я не тестировал, а несколько раз запустил с реальной рекламной, проверить, работает ли, т.к. с тестовой все окей. А если без публикаций  магазине, то ситуация такая же ? 1-3 дня подождать. Или возможно её воообще не будет, т.к. гугл не знает о чем приложение, к примеру, и не будет отправлять рекламу.

Comment: В 2017 году ещё я пробовал и тогда можно было получить реальную рекламу без публикации в сторе. А месяцев 7 назад, реклама (уже в другом приложении) ну никак не хотела показываться, пока не закинул в стор. Скорее всего они как-то проработали этот момент