# Не отображается реклама в баннере Admob

Tags: android, admob

Есть приложение, в котором в одном из активити выводится баннер `admob`. Но в почему-то он не отображается. В приложение добавил разрешение для доступа к интернету и `layout` настроен правильно. На виртуальном устройстве отображается тестовый баннер. Но когда устанавливаю приложение с play market, то баннер не отображается. Какие причины могут быть?

При это межстраничная реклама отображается без проблем.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'

public class AdsHelper {

    public static void admobLoader(Context c, Resources resources, View AdmobView) {
        String adId = resources.getString(R.string.admob_player_activity);

        if (!adId.equals("")) {
            AdView adView = (AdView) AdmobView;
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
        }

    }
}


public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ***

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        AdsHelper.admobLoader(this, getResources(), findViewById(R.id.adView));
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [AdMob, не загружается реклама](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1047950/admob-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Comment: В том вопросе моя проблема не решается. Приложение давно в маркете. Судя по тому что нашёл в интернете для моего аккаунта гугл не может в данный момент показать рекламу. На телефоне супруги реклама есть.

Comment: В логах ads failed to load 3